# can we join word press with flask?

Tags: wordpress, flask, frameworks, wordpress-theming, flask-login

I and my friend want to collaborate on a project and she knows WordPress very well and I have a good hold on python flask as the server side language. we tried to search some common way but couldn't find anything does any one have an idea ? then please help.

I have tried google search only and some WordPress document I came across flask WordPress but idk how that works

Comment: AFAIK Wordpress is written in PHP. You could always do http calls between the two. But it may be easier to stick with just one backend.